# Axiom of regularity and Axiom of infinity

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

Axiom of Infinity states the existence of the set:
$N=\{$
   $\emptyset ,$
   $\{ \emptyset \},$
   $\{\{ \emptyset \}, \{\{ \emptyset \}\}\},$
   $\{\{\{ \emptyset \},\{\{ \emptyset \}\}\}, \{\{\{ \emptyset \}, \{\{ \emptyset \}\}\}\}\},$
  $ ... \}$
indeed they are the natural numbers.
Also, Axiom of regularity states that for every non-empty set x, x contains **a member y** that is disjoint from x.

My question is, what is the **y** for $N$?

Comment: FYI, you can use `\{` and `\}` for nested { }: $\{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \}$

Comment: The $y$ for $\Bbb N$ is the very first element. That element (in your version) contains a single item, $u = \{ \emptyset \}$, but $\Bbb N$ does not contain $u$. Hence these two sets are disjoint.

Comment: So is it (I suppose) that although $u$ and N have the common element of $\emptyset$ but it still satisfies the definition of disjoint which is $u \cap N=\{\emptyset\} \cap N=\{\emptyset\}$?

Comment: Uh...$\Bbb N$ **didn't** contain the element $\emptyset$ when I gave my answer (which is why I wrote "in your version", because I thought it should). If you're going to include the emptyset in $\Bbb N$ (as I would have expected), then *it* is a really good choice for $u$, because $u \cap \Bbb N = \emptyset$, which is the definition of "disjoint".

Comment: Sorry for omitting out $\emptyset$ at first...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant $y$ is $\emptyset$.

We have $\emptyset\in \mathbb{N}$ - it's explicitly included - but trivially $\emptyset\cap\mathbb{N}=\emptyset$. Indeed, more generally we have:

> $(*)\quad$ If $\emptyset \in A$, then $\emptyset$ is an element of $A$ disjoint from $A$ as required by Regularity.

Something like $\{\emptyset\}$ would **not** work: we have $$\{\emptyset\}\cap\mathbb{N}=\{\emptyset\}\not=\emptyset$$ since $\emptyset\in\mathbb{N}$. Indeed, $\emptyset$ is the **only** choice of $y$ which works.

---

Incidentally, it's worth meditating on $(*)$ for a bit.

Suppose $A$ were a **counterexample** to regularity. Well, then by $(*)$ we must have $\emptyset\not\in A$ (otherwise setting $y=\emptyset$ would show that $A$ *isn't* a counterexample to regularity).

OK, but then we have to have $\{\emptyset\}\not\in A$ either: if $\{\emptyset\}\in A$, then we would have $\{\emptyset\}\cap A=\emptyset$ **since by the previous sentence** we know that $\emptyset\not\in A$.

Similarly, this then tells us that $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\not\in A$. And so on and so forth: we can keep "bootstrapping up" to show that $A$ can't have any elements which "can be built up from $\emptyset$."

**And that's exactly what regularity is about**: in a precise sense, regularity says "every set can be built up from the emptyset."

(That precise sense is the following. By Replacement, we can iterate Powerset through the ordinals: we get for each ordinal $\alpha$ a set $V_\alpha$ such that $V_0=\emptyset$, $V_\lambda=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}V_\alpha$ for $\lambda$ limit, and $V_{\alpha+1}=\mathcal{P}(V_\alpha)$. Over ZF-Regularity, the axiom of regularity is equivalent to "Every set is in some $V_\alpha$.")

Comment: @Aguntuk $A$ is any set at all (until the second half of the answer, at which point $A$ is an imagined counterexample to regularity).

Comment: Right, thanks for excellent answer...